# spplot doesn´t work - sppanel error

Tags: r, layouts, mapping, sp, model

I have this code (below) for plotting some information in a map, but it doesn't work, in the map appear only the error "sppanel", why I solve that?

```
library(GWmodel)

library(RColorBrewer)

data(DubVoter)

gwss.1 <- gwss(Dub.voter,vars = c("GenEl2004", "LARent", "Unempl"),
               kernel="bisquare", adaptive=TRUE, bw=48)

gwss.mc <- montecarlo.gwss(Dub.voter,vars = c("GenEl2004", "LARent",
                                              "Unempl"), kernel="bisquare", adaptive=TRUE, bw=48)

gwss.mc.data <- data.frame(gwss.mc)

gwss.mc.out.1 <-ifelse(gwss.mc.data$Corr_GenEl2004.LARent < 0.975 &
                         gwss.mc.data$Corr_GenEl2004.LARent > 0.025 , 0, 1)

gwss.mc.out.2 <-ifelse(gwss.mc.data$Corr_LARent.Unempl < 0.975 &
                         gwss.mc.data$Corr_LARent.Unempl > 0.025 , 0, 1)

gwss.mc.out <- data.frame(Dub.voter$X, Dub.voter$Y, gwss.mc.out.1,
                          gwss.mc.out.2)

gwss.mc.out.1.sig <- subset(gwss.mc.out, gwss.mc.out.1==1, select =
                              c(Dub.voter.X, Dub.voter.Y, gwss.mc.out.1))

gwss.mc.out.2.sig <- subset(gwss.mc.out, gwss.mc.out.2==1, select =
                              c(Dub.voter.X, Dub.voter.Y, gwss.mc.out.2))

pts.1 <- list("sp.points", cbind(gwss.mc.out.1.sig[,1],
                                 gwss.mc.out.1.sig[,2]), cex=2, pch="+", col="black")

pts.2 <- list("sp.points", cbind(gwss.mc.out.2.sig[,1],
                                 gwss.mc.out.2.sig[,2]), cex=2, pch="+", col="black")

mypalette.gwss.1 <-brewer.pal(5,"Blues")
mypalette.gwss.2 <-brewer.pal(6,"Greens")

map.na <- list("SpatialPolygonsRescale", layout.north.arrow(), offset = c(329000,261500), scale = 4000, col=1)

map.scale.1 <- list("SpatialPolygonsRescale", layout.scale.bar(),
                    offset = c(326500,217000), scale = 5000, col=1, fill =
                      c("transparent", "green"))

map.scale.2 <- list("sp.text", c(326500,217900), "0", cex=0.9, col=1)

map.scale.3 <- list("sp.text", c(331500,217900),"5km", cex=0.9,col=1)

map.layout.1 <-list(map.na,map.scale.1,map.scale.2,map.scale.3,pts.1)
map.layout.2 <- list(map.na,map.scale.1,map.scale.2,map.scale.3,pts.2)

library("sp")
install.packages("lattice")
library("lattice")

X11(width=10,height=12)
spplot(gwss.1$SDF,"Corr_GenEl2004.LARent",key.space = "right",
       col.regions = mypalette.gwss.1,at=c(-1,-0.8,-0.6,-0.4,-0.2,0),
       par.settings = list(fontsize=list(text=15)), main = list(label="GW
correlations: GenEl2004 and LARent", cex=1.25), sub=list(label="+
Results of Monte Carlo test", cex=1.15), sp.layout=map.layout.1)
```

Comment: When you wrote this at what point did it break? Does a simple `spplot(gwss.1$SDF,"Corr_GenEl2004.LARent")` work? As you add complexity, at what point does it break? Most people on here will skip a question like this which is a long block of code with the question "why doesn't this code work?" since we expect you to have done some basic investigation first.

Comment: Excuse Spacedman, but I tried to solve this problem changing some of parameters on code, nothing work. 

The simple spplot(gwss.1$SDF,"Corr_GenEl2004.LARent") which you propose not is exactly what I need. If you look the rest of code you see that the data are convert to a kind of map with "+" to demonstrate the level of significance to monte carlo test.

In fact, the routine doesn´t break, it generate the map with the message over:

"Error Using packet 1"
" unable to find an inherited method for function 'sppnel' for signature "matrix" "

Comment: Its not about getting exactly what you need, its about teaching you how to find out where the problem is so that in future when you get stuck you don't resort to dropping a pile of code on here and saying "this doesn't work". If you start with something that works and build up then you'll find out which line, which function, which data - sometimes which *row* of the data - causes the problem. Answer coming shortly....

Comment: Thanks Spacedman, learn about problems like this is exactly what I need and I try it. Bur I still learn about this packages with spacial thinks. Excuse-me for your time on it. I appreciate your help. This code is about "GWmodel" package in "R" and the basedata/routine is on the package. I forgot to explain, excuse me again.

Answer (score 1):

First, thanks for making a reproducible example even though it has a few issues. We like to be able to cut and paste code from here to see what your problem is so having `install.packages` is not a good idea. Also you don't say how long that Monte-carlo takes to run, which meant I nearly gave up after a minute. If you can supply data or generate test data in your script then even more people will help. You have to do everything you can to keep helpers on board to be in with a chance of getting some help.

Right. The map appeared but had an error on it. Your plot is very complex and I don't know how you've managed to construct all that code without realising where the problem is. So I've had to break it right down.

The `spplot` function  call makes the plot, and it has a load of irrelevant details. Just doing `spplot(gwss.1$SDF,"Corr_GenEl2004.LARent")` doesn't show the error but:

```
 spplot(gwss.1$SDF,"Corr_GenEl2004.LARent", sp.layout=map.layout.1)
```

still produces the error, so it must be something in `map.layout.1`. Everything else in your script is superfluous. What is `map.layout.1`?

```
map.layout.1 <-list(map.na,map.scale.1,map.scale.2,map.scale.3,pts.1)
spplot(gwss.1$SDF,"Corr_GenEl2004.LARent", sp.layout=map.layout.1)
```

That object has a few things in it, lets chop them out starting at the end.

```
map.layout.1 <-list(map.na,map.scale.1,map.scale.2,map.scale.3)
spplot(gwss.1$SDF,"Corr_GenEl2004.LARent", sp.layout=map.layout.1)
```

Oh lucky start, there's no error text this time. It must be `pts.1`. Everything else is superfluous, so let's chop all that out to give this:

```
map.layout.1 <-list(pts.1)
spplot(gwss.1$SDF,"Corr_GenEl2004.LARent", sp.layout=map.layout.1)
```

That still gives us the error. How is `pts.1` defined?

```
pts.1 <- list("sp.points", 
   cbind(gwss.mc.out.1.sig[,1],
         gwss.mc.out.1.sig[,2]), cex=2, pch="+", col="black")
```

Here you are constructing a matrix from the two columns of the data frame. Why? The help for `sp.points` says it has to be a `SpatialPoints` object. Let's make one:

```
pts.1 <- list("sp.points",
              SpatialPoints(
                  cbind(
                      gwss.mc.out.1.sig[,1],
                      gwss.mc.out.1.sig[,2])
                ), cex=2, pch="+", col="black")
map.layout.1 <-list(pts.1)
spplot(gwss.1$SDF,"Corr_GenEl2004.LARent", sp.layout=map.layout.1)
```

This works with no errors, plotting the area map and adding some points (in black, not very visible over the palette).

Now rebuild your script, adding in the extra bits, changing the palettes as you want, one piece at a time, re-running the plot (no need to re-run the MC) to check in case you've broken anything. Then you should get this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you help Spacedman, It works well. I learned a lot with you.